# How do I change text settings so that text appears in a text layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, text

I was working through a Photoshop track on Treehouse and ended up messing around with some settings while adding text. Now, I cannot see ANY text that is typed, but it does somehow seem to be entered (and likely there, just not visible). When I try to add text, here is what happens:

1. Click on Horizontal Type Tool so that I-Beam shows
2. On canvas, I make a large text area
3. A cursor shows and Blinks. The size changes depending on the font size.
4. When I type, it appears that nothing happens and the cursor remains where it is, BUT when I commit the text, the layer renames to the text I typed... but I still cannot see the text.

The background color is white and the text color is red, so I don't think it is a matter of any similar color. The settings I was experimenting with were in the character and and paragraph boxes.
halp!

Comment: Being that it's not color or size the options are opacity or "frame issues". Namely since you're using a text box you may have adjusting something so the text couldn't fit in the area provided. More likely though it was the opacity which got changed on you.

Comment: Hi there! I think your question would be a better fit for [Superuser](http://www.superuser.com). Maybe you want to take a look over there!

Answer (score 1):

Not really THE answer, but an un-fubar. I found the "reset character" option. Whatever I messed up, was unmessed up.